# PGSQL - Type cast error when ordering a column

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, casting

I am trying to sort a string column data as numeric. I am getting error like:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "HEI001"
SQL state: 22P02
```

I have tried with:

```
CAST({COL_NAME} AS integer ) ASC

NULLIF({COL_NAME}, '')::int
```

But, it didn't work. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think `HEI001` can be cast to integer?

Comment: I have both number and string in a single column.

Comment: CASE WHEN{COL_NAME} > 'A' THEN lpad({COL_NAME} , 20, '0') ELSE {COL_NAME}  END  -This works for me. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably first check whether the value is numeric (using regular expression) and then cast it since `HEI001` can no way be casted to integer unless you are trying to get it's corresponding ASCII value (as @Clodoaldo have already commented)

```
CASE WHEN COL_NAME ~ '^[0-9]+$' THEN cast(COL_NAME as integer) END
```